In Power BI, when I get data by Python script, it keep shows this error
Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error. <pi>Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\####\PythonScriptWrapper_ddec053d-7bfc-4f27-8ea3-03d81d9a6c40\PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib   File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (   File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (   File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version   File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa   File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa   File "C:\Users\####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval   File "pandas\_libs\interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject </pi>"

I reinstalled Numpy because some of people said me to try. but nothing changed...
the script I was trying to use was this
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """Exchange ID;ExchangeRate;Exchange Currency
1;1;USD
2;0,75;GBP
3;0,85;EUR
4;3,67;AED
5;1,3;AUD"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';')

# Return the transformed dataframe
df

There are 3 xlsx files and then the code...
All I want is just make the code run in my Power BI

pandas version
current updated numpy version


Your error message suggests your actual script had import os, pandas, matplotlib as its second line. Please provide a [mre] so others can easily reproduce your error.

Also, how did you reinstall numpy? Did you do pip install --upgrade numpy?

Im using numpy==1.26.4 and pandas==2.2.2 it's working fine in my PowerBI

Ok I'm gonna edit the article

The error message still says line 2, in import os, pandas, matplotlib which doesn't match your posted code. Please ensure the error message in your question is generated by the code posted in your question. Please read : [mre]

I think there are library issues in you Conda environment. Figure out what is the default python and install below versions of pandas and numpy
numpy==1.26.4 and pandas==2.2.2
further more include below line of code to ignore the warnings. for more info
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="numpy.dtype size changed")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="numpy.ufunc size changed")


current version of numpy is 1.26.4 and pandas is 2.2.2...

Have you tried the above code snippet to ignore the data type warnings?
